# NGINX headers not working with GAE app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx

I'm trying to set some Nginx headers, running on Google App Engine B4.

This is the piece of code that I've placed in my *app.yaml* file:

```
runtime_config:
  nginx_conf_http_include: nginx-http.conf
```

An this is the content of the *nginx-http.conf* file:

```
# Security headers
server_tokens off;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;
add_header Feature-Policy "geolocation none;midi none;notifications none;push none;sync-xhr none;microphone none;camera none;magnetometer none;gyroscope none;speaker self;vibrate none;fullscreen self;payment none;";
```

None of these headers are available after deployment.

Please help guys!

Comment: Which environment are you using, Flex or Standard? and which programming language?

Comment: I'm using the Standard environment and running php73. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `nginx_conf_http_include` configuration item is only available for Flex environments and PHP language, that's why it doesn't work.
The best way to approach would be to set the headers by using the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#handlers_element), more specifically the `http_headers`, for example:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    X-Foo-Header: foo
    X-Bar-Header: bar value
  # ...
```